# Let $f$ be continuous evaluate $\int\limits_3^1 x^2 f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given $f(2)=3$, $f(3)=-3$, $f^\prime (1)=2$, $f^\prime (3)=-1$, $f^{\prime\prime}(14)=15$, $f^{\prime\prime}(2)=0$ calculate $$\int\limits_3^1 x^2 f^{\prime\prime\prime} (x)\ dx$$.

I am not too sure how to start and to answer this question. I get that it is a definite integral and I need to evaluate it at $F(1)-F(3)$, but since the integral of a $f'''(x)$, I'm stuck on where to start. Do we still integrate by parts? How do I use the $f(x), f'(x),$ and $f''(x)$ for the integral?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to know $$I = \int_{x = 3}^{x = 1}x^2f''’(x)dx.$$

Using the "tabular method" with $u = x^2$ and $v = f'''(x)$ we obtain
$$I = [x^2f''(x) - 2xf'(x) + 2f(x) + 0|_{x = 3}^{x = 1}$$

Note, the "tabular method" is the same as the doing integration by parts, however, it is *typically* more efficient, but can only be used on certain problems. If you are not aware of this method I, highly, recommend you watch some YouTube videos on it. It is an easy "trick" to pick up, nevertheless, it is *extremely* beneficial.

Comment: what do i do with the numbers like f'(3)=-1 and  f′′(2)=0?

Comment: You substitute them in.

Comment: @TobyMak if you look, you actually can not just plug in the given values...i’m not sure if those are the correct values given or not.

Comment: How would I substitute it in? Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @JohnChen I am not really sure how to substitute in those given values.